# What is causing brown spots on my mint plant?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, diseases, mint

I have been rooting my mint in water and it rooted, then I found those brown spots appearing. It happened with all the mint plants I had before. I am in Egypt, and it gets morning sun and no afternoon or direct sun

*<sub>Click on photo for full size</sub>*
[image]

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that in the efforts of the cutting to make root cells from the stem nodes, it needs to transfer nutrients from the leaves to make those cells. It's pretty clear that is what is happening on the leaf edges lower down. Depriving the leaves of their normal complement of nutrients might compromise their ability to resist fungal spore growth, as in the circles further up.